# Detect the filesize via dag code before it get processed to stop 0 byte processing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, triggers, directed-acyclic-graphs

SO the problem is :
The dag is processing 0 byte files in the GCP storage bucket which later on shows error when it starts processing it .I want to detect the file size before it starts the processing and stop it from processing  . Any help would be appreciated .

I tried checking the documentation but could not find one .

Comment: I think you have to tackle the problem before Composer. How the file are deploy in your bucket? In an ideal world, it's your CI/CD pipeline that perform that copy. And before the copy, the CI/CD should validate that the files are correct.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere ,u mean that the files before landing into the bucket  should be checked not after the files gets into bucket and dag starts running ? is it .

Comment: Yes, it is. To prevent issues.

Comment: actually I have already tried it ,zero byte files are automatically getting created .So that is why I though of making a change in the code  which will stop the files(0 byte files ) getting processed by the dag . So for this I tried finding the any fucntion  which will help in detect the size  but was not able to .@guillaumeblaquiere .